# How can I make two different threads write to a variable at the exact same time? C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to build an ATM and I need to show an example of data racing.

For this I need that two threads write to a variable at the exact same time (I think).

The threads write to this variable when the button "Take out 10$" is clicked but I can't click two buttons at the exact same time which means I can't really show data-racing. Here is the code for the button click event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Form1.currAcc.getBalance() < 10)
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Insuficient Funds");
    this.Close();
  }
  else
  {
    Form1.currAcc.setBalance(Form1.currAcc.getBalance() - 10);
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Succesfully withdrawn 10$");
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

Edit: This ended up giving me a data race:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Form1.currAcc.getBalance() < 10)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Insuficient Funds");
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            currentBalance = Form1.currAcc.getBalance();
            Form5.timerStatus++;

            if (Form5.timerStatus == 1)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Form1.currAcc.setBalance(currentBalance - 10);
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Succesfully withdrawn 10$");
            }

            else{
                Form1.currAcc.setBalance(currentBalance - 10);
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Succesfully withdrawn 10$");
                Form5.timerStatus = 0;
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you only need to show how a race condition *can* affect something, or do you need to reproduce a race condition in your specific corner of the code? I ask because it is rather trivial to put together an example of code that has a race condition that will affect the outcome.

Comment: Though in all seriousness I really hope you're not **actually** writing software for an ATM and has this kind of question. If you do, stop doing it immediately. If you're building something for a class at school or something, or just for learning, fine, but if you're writing **actual** ATM software, then stop doing it. Now!

Comment: its for a class dude calm down lol. Yeah I need to show the actual race  affected something (in this case the account balance)

Comment: You can start multiple threads that checks for balance and if the balance ok withdraw 10$ in a loop. At the end you may withdrawn more money that your initial account balance.

Comment: should the variable be `volatile` then?

Comment: check out the `ParallelFor` this might be enough to get both threads to kick off at the same time

Comment: Easy to write a piece of code that shows a race condition when you don't have the proper locks or similar in place. Write a loop that runs a million times and deposits $10 into the account on each iteration. Also write a loop that runs a million times and withdraws $10 from the account on each iteration. Then run both in parallel. You might expect the final balance to be untouched (ie. if it started with $1000 in the account to begin with, you expect it to end with $1000 afterwards) but the results will vary due to race conditions.

Comment: we are supposed to simulate two people who share the same account trying to withdraw money on different ATMs at the same time and therefore setting up a data race. Not a computer running a loop a million times.

Comment: OK, but this will be hard to get predictable. The very nature of race conditions is that they're hard to reproduce accurately. However, you could start two threads that both try to withdraw money, and have both threads wait for an event (ManualResetEvent) before they execute, then start both threads before you signal the event. Basically you "talk to both guys" and tell them 3...2...1...GO! This will raise the chance of showing the race condition but will by no means guarantee it.

Comment: I can guarantee you that two button clicks won't help unless you artificially slow down the process, for instance by expanding all the steps inside and adding artificial delays between each step.

Comment: I'll try something like that. I'm thinking of putting a timer on my main form (something like 10 seconds) and once a user clicks on "withdraw 10$" it checks if the timer has reached 0. Once it reaches 0 it processes the code and hopefully simultaneously on both threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "code" answers are all good, but I think there is a conceptual thing worth pointing out: it isn't really important that your multiple threads do something at the **exact** same point in time.

The essence of such problems is: because of missing "synchronization" it can't be predicted, when those threads make their updates. Therefore you end up with different results, depending on which thread got in first.

Therefore it is already enough to have several threads increase a counter in parallel - if you do that in an "unsynchronized" way, the final result will (most likely) **not** match the expected value.

Meaning: something simple like

```
fetch the current counter
do something else that takes a bit of time
write "counter+1" to counter
```

is good enough. And it really doesn't matter that those writes happen "close" in time; the only thing that is required is that the order of reads and writes can't be predicted!

Comment: I think my solution ended up being something like this. edited my solution into the OP

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                Task.Run(() => withdraw(800m));

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Balance should be 200 unless a race condition occured.
            Console.WriteLine(balance);
        }

        static void withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            if (balance >= amount)
                balance -= amount;
        }

        static decimal balance = 1000.0m;
    }
}
```

If a race condition occurs, then `balance` will wind up negative.

When I run this, that's what happens.

If you add locking as follows, you'll always get the correct result of `200`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                Task.Run(() => withdraw(800m));

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Balance should be 200 unless a race condition occured.
            Console.WriteLine(balance);
        }

        static void withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (balance >= amount)
                    balance -= amount;
            }
        }

        static decimal balance = 1000.0m;
        static readonly object locker = new object();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to demonstrate race condition is by making use of the Parallel library as it will kick off many threads at the same time. The code below demonstrates it pretty well

```
Parallel.For(1, 11, r =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread{r}: Balance: ${_balance}");

            if (_balance < r)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread{r}: Insufficient funds ${_balance}");
                return;
            }

            _balance -= r;

            Console.WriteLine($"Thread{r}: Withdraw ${r}. New Balance is ${_balance}");
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.Read();
```

It will generate output like this

> Thread1: Balance: $20
>   Thread1: Withdraw $1. New Balance is $19
>   Thread6: Balance: $19
>   Thread2: Balance: $20
>   Thread3: Balance: $20
>   Thread4: Balance: $20
>   Thread5: Balance: $19
>   Thread8: Balance: $4
>   Thread8: Insufficient funds $4
>   Thread9: Balance: $4
>   Thread9: Insufficient funds $4
>   Thread10: Balance: $4
>   Thread10: Insufficient funds $4
>   Thread4: Withdraw $4. New Balance is $4
>   Thread5: Insufficient funds $4
>   Thread6: Withdraw $6. New Balance is $13
>   Thread2: Withdraw $2. New Balance is $11
>   Thread7: Balance: $11
>   Thread7: Insufficient funds $4
>   Thread3: Withdraw $3. New Balance is $8
>   Press any key to exit

This makes it clear that the balance the thread saw initially and the one it actually subtracts from is not the same, thread 5 for example saw $20 when it started but when it tries to withdraw $5 it gets an insufficient funds response

Comment: Oh wow, that makes it a lot more complex. O_o Not sure if you can time it tight enough to guarantee a race condition like that. Will need to think about it a bit more...